# How to ignore certain parameters when sending a form via GET?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's assume I have this simple search form:

```
<%= form_tag invoices_path, :method => 'get' do %>

    <%= text_field_tag :number %>
    <%= text_field_tag :date %>
    <%= text_field_tag :total %>

    ...

    <%= submit_tag %>

<% end %>
```

This is my controller:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @invoices = current_user.invoices.search(params)
  end

  ...

end
```

How can I *omit* certain parameters from the the `params` hash, e.g. the `total`?

I've tried things like `params.except(:total)`, however that didn't change anything.

I don't want the `total` being sent to the `search`  function, and I don't want it to appear in the URL either.

How can this be done?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you have a total input field in the first place if you don't want it submitted?

Comment: It's a datepicker field where the user can pick a date while another input field (with dateformat `YY-MM-DD`) is used for further processing. Sounds difficult, I know. But makes total sense from a usability point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input is included in the form, it will be submitted with the form unless you take special action. By the time you get into Rails code on the server, it's too late.

One approach is to disable the element immediately before the form is submitted:

Add a `never-submit` class to your input:

```
<%= text_field_tag :total, '', :class => 'never-submit' %>
```

Then use jQuery to disable any elements with that class before the form is submitted:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').submit(function() {
    $('.never-submit').prop('disabled', true);
    return true;
  });
});
```

You also may want to consider making the field something besides an `input`. Inputs are designed to allow users to submit data to your server. If that's not the intent of that field, something like a `span` (styled to look like an `input`) might be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. This is the best solution I could find so far. There's still one problem left, though: After sending the form, the input fields that had been `disabled` are re-displayed as blank in the search form. This makes sense from a logical point of view. Usability-wise it would be a lot better to re-display the values to the user, though. How can this be done?

Comment: If you are reloading the page (not using Ajax requests to submit the form), then the only way to display the data again is to send the data along with the request (which you can't do if you are, by request, not sending the data). If you aren't reloading the page, then the previous value should be maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Just doing

```
params.except(:total)
```

doesn't change the params hash, it just returns a changed hash. You can do it with the 'bang' like

```
params.except!(:total)
```

however changing the params hash is not recommended, as other actions might depend on it.

So this is the way to go for you.

```
filter = params.except(:total)
@invoices = current_user.invoices.search(filter)
```

Comment: This sounds reasonable but according to the logs the `total` param still gets sent and it also appears in the URL. What am I missing here?

Comment: You cannot make it not appear in the url if it's being submitted with the form. That being said you 'can' do it with some javascript voodoo which I will not get into nor recommend.

Comment: OK, removing it from the URL is not that important. But the `total` still gets sent from the controller to the `search` function in my model. How can this be prevented?

Answer (score 1):

params is a hash, so I think you can do this. Can you try this?

```
params.delete(:total)
@invoices = current_user.invoices.search(params)
```

Comment: When I do this, I get an `undefined method [] for nil:NilClass` error which I haven't been able to track down so far.

Comment: .delete returns the value of the deleted item, not the hash after deletion.